# success printed multiple time

Tags: php, mysql

my code running correctly but if $file have three item then after successful insert success message print three time.But I need to print message for one time at all.

```
for($i = 1; $i <= count($file); $i++){
        $insert=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO song (song_name, song_url, album,artist)
        VALUES ('".current(explode(".", $file))."', '".$file."','".$album."','".$artist."')");

        if($insert){            
            print'Success';         
        }else{
            print''.mysql_error().'';           
        }
    }
```

Comment: it will print multiple times because you are using a loop and whenever `$insert` will true prints success

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following:

```
$errors = array();

for ($i = 1, $n = count($file); $i <= $n; ++$i)
{

  $insert = mysqli_query($con, $query);

  if (!$insert)
  {
    $errors[] = mysqli_error($con);
  }

}

if (empty($errors))
{
  echo 'Success';
}

else
{
  echo 'Errors:<br><br>' . implode('<br>', $errors);
}
```

Also note that I fixed your call to `mysql_error()` to the correct `mysqli_error()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Write it this way:

```
$success = true;
for($i = 1; $i <= count($file); $i++)
{
    $insert=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO song (song_name, song_url, album,artist)
    VALUES ('".current(explode(".", $file))."', '".$file."','".$album."','".$artist."')");

    if(!$insert)
    {   $success = false;
        print''.mysql_error().'';
    }
}
if($success){
    print'Success';
}
```

This only prints "Success" only, if all queriey succeeded, and it will only print it once.

You should consider `mysqli_*` instead of `mysql_*`, as this functions are already deprecated due to security issues.

Comment: @RoyMJ shanto used this command, so I just put it in there. The question focuses on another topic, so I didn't write it in mysqli, which might only increase confusion.

Comment: :While posting as answer you should be looking to post the best method.

Answer (score 0):

try this: (you also wrote mysql_error instead of mysqli_error, this fixes it as well.)

```
$success = 0;
for($i = 1; $i <= count($file); $i++)
{
    $insert=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO song (song_name, song_url, album,artist)
    VALUES ('".current(explode(".", $file))."', '".$file."','".$album."','".$artist."')");


    if($insert)
    {
        $success = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        print''.mysqli_error($con).'';
        $success = 0;
        break;
    }


}
if($success)
print'Success';
```

Comment: This will print success, even if all queries but the last one failed. And it will also fail, if the number of $file is 0.

Comment: wrong. this will print success ONLY if ALL queries are successful. if you fail a query this wouln't be called success would it?
please check again. I'm pretty sure this code will break the loop once there is a mysql error after setting success to zero, which prevents "success" being printed.

Comment: Also, success is never set if $file is zero therefore it can never be true. hence no "success" printed.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I missed the break-command. But still $success will be undefined and might print a notice-message, if the filecount is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Stop using mysql_* functions, they are deprecated.

Try This:

```
$error = false;
for($i = 1; $i <= count($file); $i++){
        $insert=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO song (song_name, song_url, album,artist)
        VALUES ('".current(explode(".", $file))."', '".$file."','".$album."','".$artist."')");

        if($insert){    
            $error = true;    
        }
        else{
            $error = false;
            print''.mysql_error().'';    
        } 
    }
if($error) {
    print 'Success';
}
```

Comment: `if ($error) { print 'Success'; }` is semantically confusing.

Comment: @RoyMJ Point added. :)

Comment: @Sankalp :Consider the scenario, first two result in error, but the last query is successfully executed. What will be the output?

Comment: @RoyMJ I think success will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

use in this  way

```
function abc(){
    $flag = "";    
    for($i = 1; $i <= count($file); $i++)
        {
            $insert=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO song (song_name, song_url, album,artist)
            VALUES ('".current(explode(".", $file))."', '".$file."','".$album."','".$artist."')");
        if($insert)
        {
          $flag = true;
        }
        else
        {
        print''.mysql_error().''; return;
        }
    }
    if($flag == true){
       print 'success';
    }
}
```

Comment: This will print success, even if only one query succeeded.

Comment: and now ,please see modified ans